# Invoke servlet using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

Trying to invoke the servlet to invalidate the session using jQuery during before unload.The servlet URL mappings are available in web.xml.
I'm able to invoke the before unload function but the servlet call is not getting triggered.
Here follows the code base

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
  alert("Before unload"); // This alert is getting triggered"
  killSession();
}

function killSession() {
  alert("killsession"); //This too gettting triggered
  $.ajax({
    url: Infrastructure.WEB_CONTEXT / +"KillSession",
    type: 'GET'
  });
}
```

Am I missing anything? Could anyone please suggest to resolve the issue?

Comment: I have almost zero knowledge in java, but I think you need to add data how the java part looks.

Comment: why you want to do it here rather than in the java itself? Any specific reason?

Comment: your `beforeunload` should have closing tag `});`

Comment: Put the alerts after the ajax and see what happens.

Comment: could be because of the async nature of ajax, the call to ajax() is make then the page continue with the unloading which in turn aborts the ajax call

Comment: Pl post your servlet code..

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your suggestions.I have done a tiny mistake. The URL should be like Infrastructure.WEB_CONTEXT  +"/KillSession"

Answer (score 0):

Once check the url,which you given and try with by giving full details.such as port-number, ip-address and servlet-name.I hope this may resolve your problem.